# Where did the younger image of John Hurt come from?

Tags: doctor-who

The webisode *Night of the Doctor* concludes with

> the Eighth Doctor regenerating into the War Doctor, with an image of John Hurt as a young man cast in a bronze shield.

Out-of-universe - where's the image from? Hurt looks to be in his twenties, and he was certainly active then, so it's bound to be from something he did then. *I, Claudius* perhaps? Does anyone have a firm citation on what it's from?

Comment: Could have been a still from early in his career, but digital de-ageing is also a thing that can be done (Like Jeff Bridges in the last TRON movie). This is just speculation though; the nearest reference I can find is a note on the [wiki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Night_of_the_Doctor_(TV_story)) saying Paul McGann played the Doctor when he grabbed the bandolier at the end

Comment: He looked like he looked in _Crime and Punishment_, so I assume it must have been from around then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The speculation [here](http://www.slashfilm.com/doctor-who-anniversary-prelude-night-of-the-doctor-background-explained/) (which I've seen on other sites as well) is that it's from the 1979 miniseries ["Crime and Punishment"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078590/) (so he would have already been about 39, not in his twenties--the image was blurry and Hurt remained pretty thin, so there wouldn't be many telltale signs of age). I don't see any sites that have located an exactly matching shot, but you can see the top image below from "Night of the Doctor" is similar in apparent age and hairstyle to how he looked in "Crime and Punishment":

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not officially confirmed, but the hairstyle nails it. It's got to be that.

Answer (score 6):

Even though the comments here are almost two years old, I was looking for the image that matches to the one used in Night of the Doctor, and I found it ([on the BBC website](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/genome/entries/11f46c6e-a687-4162-a6ba-c0a8919a0d38)) after doing a photo search:

[image]

> "*The War Doctor, sorry Raskolnikov, **as played by John Hurt in the 1979 Crime and Punishment.***"